# how to check null value in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use following linq to sql query to get result. But it doesn't works if parentCategoryId  passed as null

```
 public static IEnumerable<Category> GetChildren(this Table<Category> source, int? parentCategoryId)
    {
        var categories = from c in source where c.ParenCategoryId == parentCategoryId select c;
        return categories;
    }
```

but  following works if null used directly in place of parentCategoryId

```
 public static IEnumerable<Category> GetChildren(this Table<Category> source, int? parentCategoryId)
    {
        var categories = from c in source where c.ParenCategoryId == null select c;
        return categories;
    }
```

Comment: check if(ParenCategoryID isEqualTo:NULL) then do what you want.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `object.Equals`, it will match on `null` values also.

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> GetChildren(this Table<Category> source, int? parentCategoryId)
{
    var categories = from c in source 
                     where object.Equals(c.ParenCategoryId, parentCategoryId) 
                     select c;
    return categories;
}
```

Comment: object.Equals will be translated to sql? if yes how query will look like?

Comment: @Reniuz Yes it will, it will be: `WHERE [t0].[ParenCategoryId] IS NULL`

Comment: @Reniuz yes, and it is optimized by Linq to Sql depending on the nullable variable's value: http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Null-check-in-Where-Clause.aspx#id_0d234c8d-7ed4-4b1e-97ba-fcc38bb4d277

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> GetChildren(this Table<Category> source, int? parentCategoryId)
{
    var categories = from c in source 
                     where (parentCategoryId != null? c.ParenCategoryId == parentCategoryId : c.ParenCategoryId == null)
                     select c;
    return categories;
}
```